# Find the fraction of games that the soccer team wins.

Tags: probability

The question I am trying to answer is: A soccer team wins 60% of its games when playing at home, and 10% of its games when playing abroad. If the team plays home 30% of the time, what fraction of the games does it win?

To solve this, I tried to compute P(W|H), P(W|A), P(H), and P(A). It says in the problem that P(H)=.3, which implies that P(A)=1-P(H)-0.7.
For P(W|H), I used the formula P(W|H)=P(W∩H)/P(H)=0.6/0.3=2. 
For P(W|A), I used the formula P(W|A)=P(W∩A)/P(A)=0.1/0.7=(1/7). 
My intuition tells me that I should add 2 and (1/7), but then how do I get my answer to be of the form (games won)/(total games played)?

Comment: It's $P(W \mid H)$ that's equal to $0.6$, not $P(W \cap H)$; similarly, it's $P(W \mid A)$ that's equal to $0.1$, not $P(W \cap A)$.  To help guide your intuition, let the soccer team play $100$ games.  They would expect to play $30$ of those games at home, and $70$ on the road.  Of the $30$ home games, how many would they expect to win?  What about of the $70$ road games?

Comment: They would win 18+7=25 games.

Comment: Yes.  Out of $100$ games altogether.  That suggests that the correct answer is $1/4$.  You should be able to use that intuition to guide you to the right analytical approach.  What did you multiply to get the $18$; what did you multiply to get the $7$?  These are the things you add together.  Keep in mind, again, that the $60$ percent and $10$ percent winning probabilities are *conditional* probabilities—conditioned on whether the game is at home or on the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W$ denote the event that the team wins.
Let $H$ and $A$ denote the events that the team plays the match at Home and Away respetively.

Then $P(H)=\frac{3}{10},P(A)=\frac{7}{10},P(W|H)=\frac{6}{10},P(W|A)=\frac{1}{10}$

Thus, $P(W)=P(W|H)P(H)+P(W|A)P(A)=(\frac{6}{10} \times\frac{3}{10}) +(\frac{1}{10} \times \frac{7}{10})=\frac{25}{100}=\frac{1}{4}$